# Progress bar & background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to use a progress bar to display on the splash screen of the application.

Though I was surprised that it didn't work simply by calling `progressBar.Value = newValue` ...

So I did some research and found out that other heavy work could block the UI thread ...

**Q1**

But what I don't really understand is that if everything is happening on the UI thread, why the progress bar is not refreshing **at all** ?

Even if I was doing "heavy work" like I/O, while finishing an I/O, I refresh the progress bar ... So shouldn't the progress bar refresh before starting another I/O ???

**Q2**

Alright, let's now say that I have to use background worker to do the heavy work and UI thread to refresh progress bar.

The heavy work I do is on loading the application. It prepares object that I will be needed later on, and after heavy work, I need to start the application with a new window etc.

When do I do it ?

Do I add a RunWorkerCompleted event handler and put every part of my remaining code of the application in that ?

And then, everything happening in the event handler, is it UI thread or another thread of Background worker ???

Thanks a lot for your help

So as asked, here is some part of my code:

The progress bar in question :

```
<ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Height="20" Value="0" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" />
```

And the worker :

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
worker.ProgressChanged += SplashManager.onProgress;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The SplashManager.onProgress method:

```
public static void onProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    screen.setProgress(((ProgressChangedEventArgs)e).ProgressPercentage);
}
```

And the screen setProgress method:

```
public void setProgress(double progress)
{
    progressBar.Value = progress;
}
```

And now I'm having an exception on progressBar.Value = progress :

the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Comment: Can you show your code? And what technology do you use? WPF, UWP, WinForms etc.

Comment: Here you are :)

Comment: Why can't you just do progressBar.Value=e.ProgressPercentage in onProgress? @HyukchanKwon

Comment: Also are you doing a `worker.ReportProgress(value)` in DoWork()?

Answer (score 2):

Progress bar control will refresh when it gets message to repaint. But while your slow method is running, messages are not processed.

You can either call `Application.DoEvents()` after changing `progressBar.Value`, which will process all waiting messages (which in extreme cases could include clicking on buttons or closing form that you are working with).

Or call (also after changing value):

```
progressBar.Invalidate();
progressBar.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like how Mykola Kovalchuk suggested. But for heavy work, it is suggested to use **BackgroundWorker** as it supports cancellation and you can interact with the UI when the thread is active, clicking a **cancel** button for example.

Q2 :

> When do I do it ?
>
> Do I add a RunWorkerCompleted event handler and put every part of my remaining code of the application in that ?

Yes, You can do other useful work while **BackgroundWorker** is busy, and when RunWorkerCompleted triggers you can call a function to do what you want.

> And then, everything happening in the event handler, is it UI thread or another thread of Background worker ???

It does run on the main UI Thread. more information here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

When using **BackgroundWorker**, you can use the **ProgressChanged** event to update the progress bar.